# Why gimp tiff file is 1.7 times smaller than matlab file for the same image

Tags: matlab, tiff, gimp, libtiff

I was surprized to see that the tiff written in matlab with lzw compression (62.5 Mo) was 1.7 times larger than the same file, opened in gimp, and exported to a new file, with lzw compression (36.6 Mo). Both seems to use libTiff 4.0 for image writing

I verified, the two files contain the exact same pixel value when opened in matlab, so no loosy compression happening.

The only difference I can found between the two files, 
using the `identify -verbose` command, the only difference is:

Gimp:

```
  Compression: LZW
  Properties:
    tiff:document: /.../gimp.tiff
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 128
    tiff:software: GIMP 2.10.5
  Artifacts:
    filename: gimp.tiff
  Filesize: 36.55MB
  Number pixels: 24.23M
```

matlab:

```
  Compression: LZW
  Properties:
    ...
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 62
  Artifacts:
    filename: matlab.tiff
  Filesize: 62.83MB
  Number pixels: 24.23M
```

So the only difference seems to be `tiff:rows-per-strip` (128 vs 62), and the presence of  `tiff:document` tag in the gimp file.
I get the similar differences using `Tiff()` in matlab.

I don't really see how these could cause such difference in file size...

But my real question is how to write such small file size in matlab ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure both use LZW compression?

Comment: yep. I've added the relevant line of the identify command

Comment: Maybe GIMP is using a [predictor](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/predictor.html)?

Comment: Interesting suggestion! Do you know how can I check that ?

Comment: Try `tiffinfo` included with libtiff or [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) to check the value of the `Predictor` tag, e.g. `python -c"from tifffile import TiffFile;print(TiffFile('gimp.tiff').pages[0].tags['Predictor'])`

Comment: Thanks for the help! You were right! A predictor tag is defined for the gimp image, but not for the matlab image. I haven't found any way to set this tag on matlab though... Any idea ?

Comment: After some basic check to the matlab tiff source code, doesn't seems possible without hacky stuf. Do you want to write an answer, I'll accept it!